# line-separated to ucwords in js

Tags: javascript

Does anybody knows how to transform **name1-name2-name3** to **name1Name2Name3** in javascript () ?? (looking for elegant solution)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. changed my answer as I now understand what you asked for. If jQuery is an option (just for the `map` functiuonality oyu can do:

```
var string2 = $.map(
        string1.split('-'),
        function(str) {
            return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
        })
    .join('');
```

You can see a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EU6Aa/1/

If jQuery is not an option you can find a simple implementation of array map [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm)

Comment: But he also want first char of name2 and name3 to be upper?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex solution, in case you (or anyone else) would prefer that:

```
var str = 'name1-name2-name3';
var str2 = str.replace(/\-(.)/g, function (m, l) {
    return l.toUpperCase(); 
});
```